# Delay loading in c#?

Tags: c#

Is there such a thing as delay loading a dll in C#? 
I know this is possible to do in C++, but what about managed code?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

.NET does that automatically, everything is loaded on demand by default.

Comment: Here's a [full explanation](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2012/Nov/03/Back-to-Basics-When-does-a-NET-Assembly-Dependency-get-loaded) of how it works in .NET.

Answer (score 2):

[This article explains](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2012/Nov/03/Back-to-Basics-When-does-a-NET-Assembly-Dependency-get-loaded) in detail how it works in .NET. Summary of key points:

> There are a number of different ways that assemblies are loaded in
>   .NET. When you create a typical project, assemblies usually come from:
>
> - The Assembly reference list of the top level 'executable' project
> - The Assembly references of referenced projects
> - Dynamically loaded assemblies, using runtime loading via AppDomain or Reflection loading

and

> .NET automatically loads mscorlib (most of the System namespace) as part of the .NET runtime hosting process that hoists up
>   the .NET runtime in EXE apps, or some other kind of runtime hosting
>   environment (runtime hosting in servers like IIS, SQL Server or COM
>   Interop).

and

> - Dependent Assembly References are not pre-loaded when an application    starts (by default)
> - Dependent Assemblies that are not referenced by executing code are    never loaded
> - Dependent Assemblies are just in time loaded when first referenced in    code
> - Once Assemblies are loaded they can never be unloaded, unless the    AppDomain that hosts them is unloaded.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is. You don't include the DLL as a reference in your project and where you want to load/use it, you call the Assembly.LoadFile method.

[This blog post](http://dranaxum.wordpress.com/2008/02/25/dynamic-load-net-dll-files-creating-a-plug-in-system-c/) does a pretty good job with code to describe how to do it.