# How to create a form in C# ONLY if a referenced DLL exists

Tags: c#, winforms, dll

I developed a Winforms C# application in which there's one single form that requires a referenced dll to work. All the other application forms (including the main one) don't need it. I want to be able to check at program start if the referenced DLL exists, and create/load that specific form only if that is true. How could I do that? In its current state, my application crashes while starting if the dll doesnt exist.
Thanks

Comment: Look into [creating a plugin-style architecture](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Creating-a-simple-plugin-b6174b62). See also: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972962.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Delay loading in c#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8344893/delay-loading-in-c)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unlike native imports, C# does all loading of dependent assemblies dynamically.  It's still possible to have a dependency failure crash the program before any user code is executed, but it is very rare.

In order to call your `Main` function (usually in Program.cs), the runtime must resolve all types used for class members, as well as types used by `Main(string[] args)` itself.  Types used by a function called from `Main` (such as your Form constructor) won't be loaded until `Main` begins executing and reaches that function.

In almost all cases, the exception related to loading the DLL will appear as an `InnerException` property on a `TypeLoadException`.  Break in the debugger when the `TypeLoadException` happens, and check the call stack.  That will let you know where to add a try/catch... and if it really does happen "while starting", it should tell you what class you need to avoid using inside `Program.cs` (or wherever your `Main` lives, if you've moved it)

The `TypeLoadException` can be caught, and if you do so, there's no hope of using the function that failed to compile, but you can still use your other classes, and even other methods in the same class as the function that couldn't compile.  You don't have to play any tricks with explicit loading or assemblies.

Here is an illustration of usage which will cause either the whole class to fail to load (`EarlyDependency`) or allow the entire class to be usable except for `MethodA` (`LateDependency`):

```
class ClassA : EarlyDependency, IComparable<EarlyDependency>
{
     EarlyDependency field;
     property EarlyDependency PropertyA { get; set; }

     int initialized = new EarlyDependency().Calculate();
     int initializedB = LateDependency.LiteralConstant;

     static ClassA
     {
         EarlyDependency localInStaticConstructor;
     }

     public ClassA()
     {
         EarlyDependency localInInstanceConstructor;

         if (new Random().NextDouble() < .000001) {
             try {
                 // you can't catch inside the function that fails to compile
                 // because code inside that function can't ever run
                 UsedByConstructor();
             }
             catch (TypeLoadException)
             {
             }
         }
     }

     public EarlyDependency MethodWithReturnType();
     public static EarlyDependency StaticMethodWithReturnType();

     public void MethodWithParameter(EarlyDependency parameter);

     public void UseIt()
     {
         LateDependency localInNonSpecialMethod;
     }

     public void Safe()
     {
         try {
             // you can't catch inside the function that fails to compile
             // because code inside that function can't ever run
             UseIt();
         }
         catch (TypeLoadException)
         {
         }
     }

     public static void UseItSomeMore()
     {
         LateDependency localInStaticMethod;
     }

     private void UsedByConstructor()
     {
         LateDependency localInMethodNamedInConstructor;
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're going to need to ensure that the referenced DLL exists and then dynamically load a separate assembly that contains the form you want to show. If you try to load the assembly normally then you app will crash in the way you've described.

Try something like this:

```
if (File.Exists("Referenced.dll")
{
    var assembly = Assembly.LoadFile("AssemblyContainingFormThatReferencesReferenced.dll");
    var type = assembly.GetType("TheForm");
    var form = Activator.CreateInstance(type) as Form;
    form.ShowDialog();
}
```

Comment: `File.Exists` doesn't check all the places the assembly could be found.  Better to try loading and catch the exception if it occurs (because there is no `TryXYZ` version of `Assembly.Load` -- if there was one that would be even better)

Comment: @BenVoigt - I took it to mean that OP was checking the existence of a specific DLL in a specific location.

Comment: I don't know the OP's exact situation, but I think of a use case like this example:  Program generates data, and has buttons for "Export to CSV" and "Export to Excel".  When doing an Excel export, the application will use an Excel.Workbook class to create the file, for CSV export it's the File.WriteAllText function built into .NET.   If a user doesn't have Office installed, then of course the Excel.Workbook class won't be usable, but it shouldn't prevent the program from running and having the "Export to CSV" option.

Comment: @BenVoigt - EBrown's suggestion of a plug-in architecture is the way to go I think.

Answer (score -1):

You could check if the file exists, and if it does, then create/load your form.

```
if(File.Exists("myLibrary.dll")
{
   MyForm frm = new MyForm();
   frm.ShowDialog();
}
```

Of course, you'll have to make sure that you are looking in the proper path.

Comment: That won't work. The `MyForm` would have needed a reference to `myLibrary.dll` to load its assembly. You have to use reflection to instantiate the form for this to work.

Comment: @Enigmativity: You're wrong, the JIT doesn't precompile the whole assembly, only each type as it is needed, and each class as it is needed.  If you have member variable of a type found in the other DLL, or such a type appears as a method signature (parameter type or return type), then the type will be needed for the compilation process earlier than you actually use it, but local variables inside a function won't trigger an assembly load until that function is actually called.

Comment: @BenVoigt - Sounds like I should put together a full test on all the variants of this code to ensure they do or do not work.

Comment: @Enigmativity That [has been done](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8344893/delay-loading-in-c#comment66322757_8344915).